# Toss Pizza Dough to Shape

Tags: pizza

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to throw a pizza dough?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13822/how-to-throw-a-pizza-dough)

When I make my pizza dough and let it rise for about two hours, I then shape the dough for the round pizza pie.  I have tried numerous times to toss it in the air and spin it on my fist to get the shape but to no avail.  My dough just rips, and its easier for me to just shape it on the counter.

Whats the trick to this??  Is the problem my actual dough?

Answer (score 2):

Tossing is a technique better suited for a video demonstration than a narrative. Fortunately we have Alton Brown (yet again...) In the Good Eats Episode "[Flat is Beautiful](http://slice.seriouseats.com/archives/2008/02/alton-brown-pizza-dough-videos.html)" AB goes into a great pizza crust recipe and demonstration of tossing and stretching your pizza.

The link I provided goes to an outside site that has both part 1 & 2 of the "[Flat is Beautiful](http://slice.seriouseats.com/archives/2008/02/alton-brown-pizza-dough-videos.html)" episode.