# Is it okay to mix bread flour and all-purpose flour when making a pizza dough?

Tags: flour, pizza

From where I'm from, I can't find 00 flour or semolina flour. The flours we have from local markets are just bread flour, all-purpose flour, cake flour, and wheat flour (with no classification).

I'm experimenting and recently created a dough mixing bread and all-purpose flour (both 1 cup plus 1 tablespoon).

I'd like to know if it's okay/safe since I don't have culinary background. :)

I'm planning to start a pizza shop sometime this year once I figure out a recipe for dough and pizza sauce that's not costy but still produces a tasty pizza. :)

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: See also: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/400/what-is-the-best-flour-to-use-for-pizza-dough?rq=1

Comment: The short answer is: Yes

Comment: More all-purpose flour (lower gluten) will make the dough easier to spread out on the pan. More bread flour will make it more elastic, so it resists spreading out. Depending on how you make the dough into its final shape (and the equipment you use, if any), this could be important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is absolutely fine. 00 flour is super-overpriced here, so much so that it is hardly ever used. Semolina is often used on the pizza peel, but really not all that often in the dough itself.

There are more recipes for pizza dough than probably anything else on the internet. Some use all-purpose flour, some use bread flour, and some use no wheat at all. You can get away anything with some experimentation.

[Serious Eats](http://www.seriouseats.com/search?term=pizza&site=all) has some of the best instruction around on everything pizza.

You don't say where you are from, but know that "all-purpose" flour has a different meaning to some people in India, and will behave differently than the medium-gluten wheat flour that is "all-purpose" to most of us. That doesn't mean you can't use [maida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maida_flour) (what is sold in much of India as "all-purpose" flour), just that it will behave differently.

There is no safety issue at all to mixing flour types. Assuming that the flours are safe individually, they will be safe combined.

Comment: Thanks! It's great to know that there are no safety issues when mixing different flour types. The dough turned out to have hard texture after my experiment of both flour having equal volume. BTW, I'm from the Philippines. Just got back from a big supermarket to check if they have 00 flour or semolina flour... but just like local markets here, they don't have it. :)

Comment: @Jolenealaska, I can help you get Italian 00 (Antimo Caputo) up in Alaska reasonably. I am an internet retailer of it at BrickOvenBaker.com, and I don't usually post that, but I think I'm helping by suggesting there are places online that should be able to get you Italian 00 flour up in AK (or other in HI, PR, GU etc) without shipping costs getting out of hand. My comment is intended to help you and others finding it hard to get 00 Flour in local stores.