# What is the difference between cake flour and AP flour?

Tags: flour

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between various types of flour?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-the-difference-between-various-types-of-flour)

I am baking a Yule Log (Buche de Noel) for solstice and the recipe I generally use calls for a lot of coconut and pecans and I have people who don't like those things coming to dinner, so I am looking for another recipe. The recipes I am finding though all call for cake flour and I don't bake a lot of cakes so I didn't want to buy it just for this recipe, can I turn AP flour into cake flour or what is the difference between the two? I have bread flour and AP flour in the pantry.