# Can I use “All-Purpose flour” instead of “cake flour”?

Tags: baking, substitutions, dough, flour

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between various types of flour?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-the-difference-between-various-types-of-flour)

The recipe calls for cake flower, I have all-purpose flour. Can I use what I have? Or should I go get the cake flour? I know some things can be substituted, but not all the time. I’m  making a n old fashioned pineapple upside-down cake.

Comment: This duplicates [What is the difference between cake flour and AP flour?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10160) which was merged with [What is the difference between various types of flour?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/356) The short answer is *no*; the long answer is *yes* if you happen to be very experienced with the recipes and flours and know how to adjust ratios and/or baking times to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

This can depend on the specific recipe and the goal, but in general know that cake flour has a lower resulting gluten content than all-purpose flour, thereby resulting in the cake having a "lighter" texture. Experimentation with the specific recipe can tell you whether it matters, but in general I would caution substituting if any of the following conditions are called out by the recipe;

- a very specific kneading/mixing time, i.e. with breads
- a specific attention is called to the temperature, i.e. with pie crusts
- the cake should have a very fluffy, spongy, or otherwise specific texture (as opposed to a more loose end result as with cake brownies or other hybrids where some flex either way could yield a nice result)

In some recipes, and especially mediated by the type of fat you use*, it may not matter if you use cake flour. However, if you want to make a spongier or fluffier loaf of cake, it will be detrimental to have all-purpose flour as the main building block. Some recipes can be specifically cut with cake flour to reduce gluten in the end result. The inverse obtains as well.

*If a recipe with a higher gluten flour calls for a room-temperature liquid fat (canola oil), and you substitute it with a lower gluten flour and a room-temperature solid fat (i.e. coconut oil, shortening) you can tweak to approximate a similar end result with pleasant nuances. I do this with otherwise oatmeal and whole-wheat cookies relying on a puree (i.e. pumpkin, sweet potato) for flavor, and cut in some APF with coconut oil instead of vegetable oil, thus resulting in a crisp cookie with a pleasant toothiness.